# Retrieving failing package and error message in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, error-handling

I want to make a general error handling package that should be called from my other packages when something goes wrong. In this error handling package I want to log what task failed and the reason for the failure. How can I retrieve this information?

I'm using the Control Flow Failure precedence constraint to point out a Execute Package Task that executes the error handling package when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it, the only thing I needed was the executionid and the logging in a sql server so I could run a query like this:

SELECT     event, computer, operator, source, starttime, endtime, message
FROM sysdtslog90
WHERE     (executionid = '?') AND (event = N'OnError')
ORDER BY starttime DESC

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following article by Jamie Thomson that shows how to get the error description using a Script Task.

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/08/08/1969.aspx

You can find an alternative approach to Error Handling in SSIS on an article from SQL Server Central

[Error Handling in SSIS](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+%28SSIS%29/62662/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that article uses a Script Component in the Data Flow and is irrelevant to my case where I'm in the Control Flow and using a Script Task.